# Removed UIWEBVIEW from Ionic project but still getting rejected by the app store

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, uiwebview, wkwebview

At this point I've tried everything online to no avail.  I keep getting rejected by the Apple store for using UIWEBVIEW even though I've followed all of the steps to remove it.  In fact, I'm searching my entire project for UIWEBVIEW and can't find it.

So far I've done the following:

According to Ionic's website:
Add `<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />` to your config.xml file.

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save
```

removed ios platform then re-added the latest cordova-plugin-ionic-webview and ios.  Initially when I searched the project I saw several uiwebview references but now there are none and I'm still getting rejected by Apple.

```js
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="" version="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="20" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20.png" width="20" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@3x.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="48" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-24@2x.png" width="48" />
        <icon height="55" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-27.5@2x.png" width="55" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="88" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-44@2x.png" width="88" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="172" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-86@2x.png" width="172" />
        <icon height="196" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-98@2x.png" width="196" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1125" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2436h.png" width="2436" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2436" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2436h.png" width="1125" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
        <icon height="216" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-108@2x.png" width="216" />
        <splash height="2688" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2688h~iphone.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2688h~iphone.png" width="2688" />
        <splash height="1792" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-1792h~iphone.png" width="828" />
        <splash height="828" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-1792h~iphone.png" width="1792" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.2">
        <variable name="" />
    </plugin>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" platform="ios" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string>We use your location for full functionality of certain app features.</string>
    </edit-config>
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "",
  "homepage": "/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.23.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.22.0-beta-1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": "^10.1.1",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": "^5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^7.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.3.5",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.1.0",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.4.1",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^5.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^7.9.1",
    "geofire": "^5.0.1",
    "geofirex": "^0.1.0",
    "ionicons": "^4.5.10-0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": {
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GPS_REQUIRED": "true"
      },
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "28.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "
      },
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": {
        "IOS_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION": "~> 7.0.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

i really don't know what to do at this point, Apple keeps rejecting me even though there's no reference to uiwebview.  I've followed Ionic's documents suggesting to install the latest version of ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save

cordova -v
9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

ionic cli -v
6.0.1

I also searched the entire project in xCode for all references of UIWebView and manually replaced it with WKWebView and it still got rejected.

I also searched the entire plugins dir for any occurrence of UIWebView
[image]

I've gone back and manually upgraded all of the plugins.

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.23.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.22.0-beta-1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": "^10.1.1",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": "^5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^7.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.3.6",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.1.0",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.4.1",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^5.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^7.9.1",
    "geofire": "^5.0.1",
    "geofirex": "^0.1.0",
    "ionicons": "^4.5.10-0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
```

I've added the following wkwebview only setting in xCode:
[image]

But I’m still getting this from Apple:
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView

When I search in my project in VS Code I don’t get any references to UIWebView. But when I search in xCode I get the following:

```js
/**
 When web application loads Add stuff to the DOM, mainly the user-defined settings from the Settings.plist file, and
 the device's data such as device ID, platform version, etc.
 */
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    NSLog(@"Resetting plugins due to page load.");
    CDVViewController* vc = (CDVViewController*)self.enginePlugin.viewController;

    [vc.commandQueue resetRequestId];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:CDVPluginResetNotification object:self.enginePlugin.webView]];
}
```

Some of these classes in xCode are prepended with

#if !WK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY

So i’m assuming it’s only to be used if I don’t have the wk webview only setting…which I do. This is extremely frustrating. I even removed and re-added the ios platform using the latest version 5.1.x

Upon further inspection, if I’m looking at these classes in xCode I can see that for these classes they’re for inAppBrowser.

CDVUIInAppBrowserViewController
But this isn’t even using UIWebView, it has a conditional statement:

#ifdef __CORDOVA_4_0_0
#import <Cordova/CDVUIWebViewDelegate.h>
#else
#import <Cordova/CDVWebViewDelegate.h>
#endif
and it’s implementing an interface that has a name containing UIWebView

@interface CDVUIInAppBrowserViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, CDVScreenOrientationDelegate>
There are no more references to UIWebView in the entire project, instead there are a few classes that have a name containing UIWebView.

Comment: The 'Known Plugin Issues' section here: https://ionic.io/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation has a list of plugins to remove.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also check the Plugins to make sure they have been updated.  You have a quite a bit of plugins there so maybe one of them still has references UIWebView.

Comment: I've searched my entire project for UIWebView and it doesn't show up.  It would seem as if there should be some guide to specifically mention which plugins may be using UIWebView.  If a global search doesn't return any results is it still likely one of the other plugins is using it?

Comment: If a textual search does not bring up any results, then chances are a plugin is importing a prebuilt library that uses UIWebView.